# Creating a function that will retrieve certain information from both a list and a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

In the for loop I need to use the list emner first object to search for the tags in the dictionary karakterer. 
The for loop i need assistence on is the one under #search using fag. I want it to retreive the first object in the list emner and return the result from the dictionary karakter. So if I write geografi, i want it to return GEO200 and GEO300.

```
karakterer = {"INFO100":"A","INFO200":"B", "ECON110":"B", "ECON220":"A",
          "GEO200":"C", "GEO300":"E"}

emner = [("informasjonsvitenskap","INFO100"),("økonomi", "ECON110"),
     ("geografi", "GEO200"), ("informasjonsvitenskap","INFO200"),
     ("økonomi", "ECON220"),("geografi", "GEO300")]

def emneliste():
    print("Velg fag og/eller emnenivå (<enter> for alle")
    global emner
    global karakterer
    #this code works
    fag = input('Fag: ')
    nivå = input('Nivå: ')
    if fag == '' and nivå == '':
      for x in karakterer:
          if x in karakterer:
              print(x+' '+karakterer[x])

    #search using fag
    for x in emner:
        rangefag = (int(re.search(r'\d+',x).group()))
        fag = int(fag)
        if fag == informasjonsvitenskap:
           if rangefag in emner[0]:
               print(x+' '+karakterer[x])
        if fag == økonomi:
            if rangefag in emner[0]:
               print(x+' '+karakterer[x])       
        if fag == geografi:
            if rangefag in emner[0]:
               print(x+' '+karakterer[x])

    #search using nivå
    #this code works 
    for x in karakterer:
        rangenivå = (int(re.search(r'\d+',x).group()))
        nivå = int(nivå)
        if nivå == 100:
            if rangenivå in range(100,200):
                if x in karakterer:
                    print(x+' '+karakterer[x])
        elif nivå == 200:
            if rangenivå in range(200,300):
                if x in karakterer:
                    print(x+' '+karakterer[x])
        elif nivå == 300:
            if rangenivå in range(300,400):
                if x in karakterer:
                    print(x+' '+karakterer[x])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand all the usages of the range function or the regex searches, but this gets the data from both the list and the dictionary

```
fag = input('Fag: ')

values = [y if x == fag for x, y in emner] 

for v in values:
    print(karakterer[v])
```